# Prepare dataset in CSV for machine learning?

Tags: data, machine-learning, csv

I have a dataset consisting of CSV files (weather data).
My issue is to clean the wrong values or empty values before using the dataset for machine learning.
Right now I have to copy by hand the data from an external CSV using Excel (and some built-in functions). 
My objectives are to replace data and merge CSV files.

To automate this process, is it a must to write a script that manipulates CSV or does a software like that already exist?

I tried Apache Nifi but then I need to transform the CSV to a database, do SQL on the database and transform back to CSV again... Not the best solution I guess.

Comment: I’d do this with Python and Pandas, but it does require programming.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer, this is what I started to do at first but I'm still learning programming actually... If there's no other way, I'll have to code a script myself for sure

Comment: The good news is that if you get familiar with Python and Pandas, you will find them exceptionally useful in machine learning. I would suggest installing Python using the Anaconda distribution as it makes it easy to set up with all the technical libraries you might need. https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

Comment: Yeah you're right... Thank you very much, I already have Anaconda installed. In fact I coded a script which manipulates csv files through simple python objects (dict) and not using pandas. I will try it again with pandas !

Comment: Can you define `clean the wrong values or empty values`, and can you program in Python? Does `clean` mean `remove`?

Comment: Glorfindel : Thanks for your edit
@Mawg I can program with Python yes (at least I'm supposed to be able to), and there's no removal strictly speaking it's about replacing values in order to have a clean dataset. My targets to do so, are : the timestamp and the header (name of the column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import csv

    with open(csvFilePath, 'rt') as csvFile:
        rows = (line for line in csv.reader(csvFile, dialect='excel'))
        for row in rows:
           *** do your cleaning here ***               
           *** rows is a list of strings ***
```

Is that enough, or do you need more?

There ***might*** be an existing app that helps, but it is unlikely to do exactly what you want, and coding this is utterly trivial (and left as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Comment: See [this page](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/). You will probably read the entire, excellent, eBOok

Comment: Wow excellent, thank you very much it's exactly what I needed to handle complex cases ! I will dive into the eBook later on :)

Comment: Lol. I have been mentioning it quite a lot lately. So glad I found it; it's a real gem :-)